# I'm trying to create a new repository on github but can't get my ssh key

Tags: ssh, command-line, terminal, repository

I cant make a repository because I don't have an ssh key on git hub but I don't know how to get that I fallowed a video and it was going good until he copy pasted it and that won't work for me. I tried clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
 but when I hit CTRL V nothing pastes.

Comment: did you try `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and then copy what appeared and then paste?

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

Then:

```
xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Key should be in your clipboard now.

Log-in to Github > Click on your profile photo > Click `Settings` > Click on `SSH and GPG` in your sidebar > Click `New SSH key` or `Add SSH key` > Enter a title like "My Linux machine" > Paste your key into the Key field.

Done.